# count missing value by index groups

Tags: python, pandas, missing-data

I just want to count all NA values grouped by the first index, name_of_collection. And print the each collection name corresponding to their number of NA values.
Could anybody help me? Thank you so much!!
The expected output:

| name_of_collection | # of NA |
| --- | --- |
| autoglyphs_Data_Clean | 48 (for example) |
| veefriends_Data_Clean | 57 (for example) |

[dataset:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eN3yC.jpg)

Comment: Please share some sample data *as text, not as image*, ideally following the instructions on [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20159305/15873043).

Comment: Please try and paste a sample dataset as text. That way, people can copy-paste your data and help you faster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let "col" be the name of the column where you're looking for the NA values and df your dataframe. Then this should work :

```
df["is_na"] = df["col"].isna()
df.groupby("name_of_collection")["is_na"]
.sum()
.reset_index()
.rename(columns={"is_na":"# of NA"})
```